# Reorganize a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydash

Assuming I have the following:

```json
[
  {"sku": "ZZZ", "name":"None name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "AAA", "name":"One name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "BBB", "name":"The name", "shelf": None},
  {"sku": "CCC", "name":"A name"}
]
```

I am trying to find the best (most elegant maybe) way to:

1. Add "shelf": 'Default' when missing or set to `None`
2. Split the list per shelf, so the one above should give out two named lists: one for Default and one for '10'
   This is the desired output:

```json
[
  {"10":[
    {"sku": "ZZZ", "name":"None name"},
    {"sku": "AAA", "name":"One name"}]
  },
  {"default":[
    {"sku": "CCC", "name":"A name"},
    {"sku": "BBB", "name":"The name"]
  }
]
```

Using `pydash.collections.for_each(initial_list,reorganize)` I can sort the first problem, but I am not sure how to deal with the second.

```py
def reorganize(x):
    if 'shelf' not in x: x['shelf'] = 'default'
    if x['shelf'] is None: x['shelf'] = 'default'
```

I also do not thing this is the best way to solve the problem.
Reason for pivoting the list is because I need to call an API which needs the shelf as parameter and cannot accept multiple shelf at the same time (but accepts multiple SKUs).

Comment: do you want to get only SKU's for seperate `shelf`s? is using pandas ok for you?

Comment: @armamut `pandas` is ok even if I have not considered it. It's a standalone SW. I need to pivot/reorganize everything. I probably need to create a new empty list and in the same def append whatever I need under a key I must create if not exist ... mmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
input_list = [
  {"sku": "ZZZ", "name":"None name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "AAA", "name":"One name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "BBB", "name":"The name", "shelf": None},
  {"sku": "CCC", "name":"A name"}
]

output_dict = {}
for d in input_list:
    output_dict.setdefault(d.pop('shelf', 'default') or 'default', []).append(d)
```

`output_dict` is:

```sh
{10: [{'sku': 'ZZZ', 'name': 'None name'}, {'sku': 'AAA', 'name': 'One name'}], 'default': [{'sku': 'BBB', 'name': 'The name'}, {'sku': 'CCC', 'name': 'A name'}]}
```

Let's explain the code:

- `pop` returns the `shelf` entry and removes it from the dictionary;
  if `shelf` is not present, `pop` returns the default value, i.e. its
  second (optional) argument (`'default'` in this case). The `or` is
  used to handle the cases when `shelf` is present, but with a `None`
  or '' value: in this case, `default` is used.
- `setdefault` returns the value of the dictionary with key equal to
  the first argument, or it returns the second argument if the key is
  not present.
- `append` adds the current dictionary (with `shelf` entry removed by `pop`) to the list corresponding to its `shelf` value.

Comment: very nicely done. Didn't realize we can give `or` for keys in `setdefault()`

Comment: Love it, it's compact and works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [
  {"sku": "ZZZ", "name":"None name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "AAA", "name":"One name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "BBB", "name":"The name", "shelf": None},
  {"sku": "CCC", "name":"A name"}
]

lst2 = list()
for dct in lst:
    v = dct.pop("shelf", None) or "default"
    for d in lst2:
        if d.get(v):
            d[v].append(dct)
            break
    else:
        lst2.append({v: [dct]})
print(lst2)
```

Output:

```
[{10: [{'sku': 'ZZZ', 'name': 'None name'},
       {'sku': 'AAA', 'name': 'One name'}]},
 {'default': [{'sku': 'BBB', 'name': 'The name'},
              {'sku': 'CCC', 'name': 'A name'}]}]
```

Breaking it down:

1. Define a list, `lst2`, to become the output list.
2. Iterate through the dictionaries of `lst`, and define a variable, `v`,
   to check if the value of the soon-to-be-created-dictionary should be the value of the current dictionary's `"shelf"` key, or `"default"`.
3. Iterate through each dictionary of the `lst2`. If coresponding key are found, append the dictionary to the key of the `lst2`.

Answer (score 0):

my take on the question, with pandas:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {"sku": "ZZZ", "name":"None name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "AAA", "name":"One name","shelf": 10},
  {"sku": "BBB", "name":"The name", "shelf": None},
  {"sku": "CCC", "name":"A name"}
])
df.shelf = df.shelf.fillna('default')
for shelf, skus in df.groupby('shelf').sku.apply(list).items():
    print(shelf, "=>", skus)
>>>
10.0 => ['ZZZ', 'AAA']
default => ['BBB', 'CCC']
```